# Remove Username and just show Name in Author Metabox in backend

Tags: metabox, author

In the Author Metaboxes for Posts / pages / custom types, it shows:  Name (Username)

Is there anyway to customize this to just show Name only?  Or maybe Name and Role?

I am pretty sure if it done with wp_dropdown_users but I'm not sure how to use it to make it do what I want and add it as function.

Thank you.

Edit: Screenshot for clarification. This is from the backend of the post editor.  My username is Test and my name is John Smith in this example.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot in relation to the Author metabox you are referring to? Is it the back-end Author (select) box or the Author in the front-end?

Comment: Interesting question. There is an attribute to choose what field to display in option and default value is set to display just a name. So, wordpress developers call this function with attribute to show "name (nickname)". There are 2 filters used, one for filtering parsed arguments and query vars, second one for filtering html output. Tried first filter, but it leads to an error if I just unset username from a fields argument. Second filter sounds dirty and requires to just find positions of "()" and cut them from a string. Maybe someone smarter can solve this more natively.

Comment: Added a screenshot as per requested to help clarify